# content_main.xml is not generated in my android project

Tags: android

I am using android studio 2.1 for developing android application, i am a beginner and trying to learn android. I am creating a new project by clicking on File->New->New Project->(giving project name, selecting minimum versions etc)->selecting blank activity->(Giving activity name, Layout name, checking 'Generate Layout File')-> Finish.

Looking at the project structure, I found that in app/res/layout folder only one xml file activity_main.xml is found while another file content_main.xml is not generated. In all examples available on internet, content_main.xml file is there. please help me what to do, thanks is advance.

Comment: You don't need a content_main

Answer (score 2):

By saying `blank activity` I think you meant **Empty Activity**. Try choosing **Basic Activity** while creating. It will generate both the .xml files.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

may be you had selected empty activity at the time of project creating so now you can design your UI in activity_main.xml.

no need additional content_main.xml.

Answer (score 0):

The android documentation page is slightly misleading. You have to use **Basic Activity** instead. Then you will get two layout files namely activity_main.xml and content_main.xml.